# Remove all items in a list from another list

Tags: python

If the user enters "search Facebook" then the program will recognize the keyword "search" and know that the user wants to search the web. For the program to search what they want, I need to remove any of the keywords in `web_keys = ["search", "google", "bing", "internet", "online"]` from their input and just search for the other text with the input, in this case "Facebook". I'm using the code below, but it doesn't remove the keywords from the input.  How can I remove any keywords from the input?

```
web_keys = ["search", "google", "bing", "internet", "online", "google"]

def web(q_input):
    while any(i in web_keys for i in q_input.split()):
        try:
            q_input.remove(web_keys)
        except AttributeError:
            break

        webbrowser.open('https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio7-LNjqbQAhWDmBoKHTLJAHMQPAgD#hl=en&q='+q_input)
        print("Searching..." + "'" + q_input + "'")
```

Comment: Sorry but your question seems to be incomplete, could you kindly complete the question?

Comment: Hey! Sorry about the first post, I mistakenly clicked post to early.

Comment: shows your q_input, please

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that worked for me - fixing some indentations and other issues:

```
web_keys = ["search", "google", "bing", "internet", "online"] # There was an extra google here

def web(q_input):
    for i in q_input.split(): # A simplified version breaking the while loop down to a for loop and an if
        if i in web_keys:
            q_input=q_input.replace(i,'') # Don't forget to assign the results back to q_input
    q_input=q_input.strip() # Remove leading and trailing extra spaces
    webbrowser.open('https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio7-LNjqbQAhWDmBoKHTLJAHMQPAgD#hl=en&q='+q_input)
    print("Searching..." + "'" + q_input + "'")

web('google search Stack Overflow online')
```